# Re-sizing the Opera window

Tags: window, resize, opera

I have trouble when re-sizing the Opera window specifically in Ubuntu 20.04.1. When I hover over the edge of any other window the cursor changes to the re-size cursor (aero_ew, pictured) for a reasonable area, of about 10 pixels or 3-4mm in width.This is what the cursor changes into when I'm re-sizing a window
[image]

But on the Opera window that area is much smaller (like 2 pixels) and its really annoying. I want to resize the window but the cursor just refuses to find that edge. If you know how to enlarge that area which allows you to re-size the windows could you please let me know?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 , I think it's the latest version right now. Also it says that the Windowing System is X11. I don't know if that's relevant.

Comment: @user10440380: did you solve the problem? I'm also having the same issue on ubuntu 21.04.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not the solution that you are hoping for but since the problem is annoying, using Alt-F8 for now may help.